# Unable to create a list of internal testers Android

Tags: android

I have created an internal release of the android App. Following google's instructions, I clicked on testers, clicked on Create Email List, added the List name, then an email address, for the life of me, it won't let me save, the "Save Changes" button is greyed out.
There is an option to add email from a csv file. I saved one email address in that file, tried to upload and got: "sundarpichai@gmail.com" is not a valid email address. I'm lost am I missing something? You will find the screenshot
https://share.getcloudapp.com/NQuK7rbW

Comment: In the screenshot you posted it says below the email field: "Press enter to add", did you press enter?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you know you can add images to your posts? That would help others with the same problem in the future, in case the link goes down!

Comment: Trust me, I tried, I could not find a button that says, "upload image".

Comment: Thank you @TechRando. My biggest facepalm moment.

Comment: I know this is old but the interface is incredibly misleading. Once you have added the email to the page, you also have to click the tickbox to the left of each of your email addresses and then press Save. It's very unintuitive and I've wasted many hours trying to figure out why I can't add testers, but hopefully this helps someone.